# rubyonrails error when update to gem 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby 1.8.6, and I would like to update. 
The server company I am with said to run command:

```
gem update rails
```

ERROR: Error installing rails:

```
activesupport reqiores Ruby version >= 1.8.7.
```

Also I am working on the company's live site, any help on this matter is appreciated thank you!

Comment: you are trying to update rails, but you have to update ruby first... what is your platform? are using rvm?

Comment: linux and no, i tried installing ruby 1.8.7 got same error.Perhaps I used wrong command, not all that familiar with ruby

Comment: Install ruby and rails with a version manager(rbenv or rvm) so that you could switch between different ruby/rails versions. And you have used gem update rail instead of rails.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to update ruby gem -

```
gem update --system
```

Use `gem update` to update all installed gems to their latest versions.

Another option is to manually install ruby -

Check this link for further process http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3#page13

Comment: I got the same error
ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
        rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7.

Comment: @user1827377 plese check you are not using two parallel versions of ruby

Comment: Sorry this is my 1st time dealing with ruby, where would that be located?

Comment: @user1827377 try this one and let me know then sudo apt-get install ruby-full get ruby from here http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/72085/rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p302.exe

Comment: @user1827377 you are using linux na ?

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try after lunch. Thanks

Comment: @user1827377 and let me know the results then :)

Answer (score 0):

you can update your ruby by:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```

But I really recommend you to use RVM (Ruby Version Manager) instead.

Comment: Update from 1.8 to 1.9 is not something to be taken lightly.

Comment: yea I read that somewhere. I tried installing rvm via
 
(\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby) but I got curl (60) certificate error

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, than `sudo apt-get install curl`... take a look here: http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/installrvmlinux.htm